# How to get a value from a HTML form (using Html.EnumDropDownListFor) in ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am new in ASP.NET. I have implemented a form that accepts values from a C# enum:

```
<form method="get">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Curve Name:</label>
        @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(x => x.Type, new { @id = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="valueDate">Value Date:</label>
        <input id="date-input" type="date" class="form-control" name="valueDate">
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="display()">Search</button>
</form>
```

Then in a javascript function, I want to retrieve the value as an string, however, I am obtaining an int. I was trying to cast the result:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function display() {
    var type = @(EnumEx)document.getElementById("form-control").value;
}
```

However, it is not working because the javascript code is not recognized in C#.

Comment: .toString() JavaScript function will convert it to a string

Comment: @GHDevOps .toString() on a number will return the number as a string. It would not return the enum value name or the option text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you can't mix C# and JavaScript like that.  Server-side code runs on the server, client-side code runs in the browser.  Both happen at entirely different times and in entirely different environments.

For the JavaScript, it sounds like what you want is the selected option's *text*, not its value.  As the property name implies, this gets the value:

```
var type = document.getElementById("form-control").value;
```

To get the text, you might do something like this:

```
var element = document.getElementById("form-control");
var type = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
```

For example:

```js
var element = document.getElementById("form-control");
element.addEventListener('change', function () {
    var type = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
    console.log(type);
});
```

```html
<select id="form-control">
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It should be noted that if the enum values are decorated with DisplayAttribute, the text values within each <option> tag will be based on the properties of the attribute instead of being the value name in the enum. Short of defining the enum again in Javascript (as an array of strings since JS doesn't actually have enums) there would be no way to get the actual value name when DisplayAttribute is used.